# Jekyll — Change layout if page is a post?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In a Jekyll layout, is there any way to detect if the page is a normal page or a post? I want to display post titles, but not page titles. Like this:

```
{% if page.is_post? %}
    <h2>{{ page.title }}</h2>
{% endif %}
{{ content }}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since Jekyll 2.0, you can use [Front Matter Defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/):

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""      # empty string for all files
      type: posts   # limit to posts
    values:
      is_post: true # automatically set is_post=true for all posts
```

then you can use `{{ page.is_post }}` to check whether the page is post.

No idea why Jekyll doesn't set `page.type` by default.

Answer (score 14):

Declaring a post layout in front-matter is not enough?
If your post uses a `post` layout you are sure the page is a post and you don't need to add extra logic

```
---
layout: post
---
```

BTW a quick and dirty (very dirty) way to determine the page type consists to check the page path, generally posts are under the `_posts` directory so you can check it

```
{% if page.path contains '_posts' %}
This page is a post
{% else %}
This page is a normal page
{% endif %}
```

Comment: My layout is about 50 lines of HTML, so I don't want two copies that differ by only one line. Thanks for the info though, you've given me an idea how to do this!

Comment: @Josh: You can apply a layout to another.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest and most straightforward way to determine if its a page or a post is to use `page.id`.

```
{% if page.id %}
    This is a post
{% endif %}
```

I personally use this method in my layouts page to determine if its a page or post so I can show links to previous/next posts only if its a post.

**_layouts/default.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% include head.html %}

<body>

{% include header.html %}

{{ content }}

<!-- If this is a post, show previous/next post links -->
{% if page.id %}

{% if page.previous.url %}
<a href="{{page.previous.url}}">{{page.previous.title}}</a>
{% endif %}

{% if page.next.url %}
<a class="button is-link ellipsis" title="{{page.previous.title}}" href="{{page.next.url}}">{{page.next.title}}</a>
{% endif %}

{% endif %}

{% include footer.html %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly for conditional content display in answer to the question posted--thanks! (Not sure why this needed to be voted down, other than some people seem to enjoy doing that on SO.)

Comment: All documents in a collection have an id too, so this method doesn't work if your site has collections other than posts.

Comment: @kslstn you can check if it is either a post or a collection using `page.collection`. For example, the following condition would be true if it is a collection and false if it is a post: `{% if page.id and page.collection %}`

Comment: @kimbaudi unless you have posts inside a collection :)

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I solved the problem:

1. Create a symlink from `_layouts/post` → `_layouts/main`
2. Change the layout of posts to `post`:

   ```
   ---
   layout: post
   ---
   ```
3. Add an if statement in `_layouts/main` like so:

   ```
   {% if page.layout == 'post' %}
       <h2>{{ page.title }}</h2>
   {% endif %}
   ```

A better way to solve this might be to use includes and have two separate layouts like @dafi said though.

Comment: I didn't create a symlink, solo step 3 work fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Posts come with a `date` variable, while pages do not.

While not bulletproof, this solution requires no additional configuration:

```
{% if page.date %}
    <h2>{{ page.title }}</h2>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Posts also come with an `id` variable. I personally prefer to use `page.id` to check if its a post.

Answer (score -1):

you can set type, in `_config.yml` defaults for all types:

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "pages"
    values:
      type: "pages"
```